# Filter a tags by content inside them with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to search among `<a>` tags, and only show the ones that meet the requirement. So when you load the page, all `<a>` tags are visible. When you type into the search box, I want to filter the `<a>` tags by the title inside them.

```js
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#content').children().children().children("p").each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent()[search && $(this).text().toLowerCase().match('^' + search) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
    <div class="content">
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <img>
                    <p class="title">John</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <img>
                    <p class="title">Jenny</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <img>
                    <p class="title">Jane</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <img>
                    <p class="title">Jack</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
     </div>
```

The above javascript doesn't work. So how do I filter here by the title?

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically call method on object?

Comment: Use this overload of `.toggle` : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

Comment: You have an type error `class="content"` and `$('#content')`

Comment: replace `.text()` with `.attr("title")`  (and as others pointed out `$(".content")`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `filter()` to find the `.title` elements which do not meet the search requirements and then hiding their parent `.box`. Note however, that for a case-insensitive search you will need to extend the `:` jQuery operator with you own logic which is a variation of `:contains`, something like this:

```js
jQuery.expr[':']['contains-insensitive'] = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

var $box = $('.box');
$('#search').on('input', function(e) {
  $box.show();
  $('.title').filter(`:not(:contains-insensitive('${this.value}'))`).closest('.box').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="content">
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <img>
      <p class="title">John</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <img>
      <p class="title">Jenny</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <img>
      <p class="title">Jane</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <img>
      <p class="title">Jack</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I want to do. I want to filter only by the title and the other content.

Answer (score 1):

`#content` targets an element with ID as `content`. You have the class `content` assigned to the `div`, which should be targeted as `.content`.

```js
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.content').children().children().children("p").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent()[search && $(this).text().toLowerCase().match('^' + search) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="content">
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <img>
      <p class="title">John</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <img>
      <p class="title">Jenny</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <img>
      <p class="title">Jane</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box">
      <img>
      <p class="title">Jack</p>
      Other content.
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/PapKjr

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
            var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $('.content').children().find("p").each(function() {console.log($(this).text());
                $(this).parent().parent()[search && $(this).text().toLowerCase().match('^' + search) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
    <div class="content">
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <img>
                    <p class="title">John</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <img>
                    <p class="title">Jenny</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <img>
                    <p class="title">Jane</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
            <a>
                <div class="box">
                    <img>
                    <p class="title">Jack</p>
                    Other content.
                </div>
            </a>
     </div>
```